# firebase-auth.html - Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Tags: polymer-1.0, firebase-authentication, firebase-polymer

I cloned the following Polymer todo-list app from https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list and after setting it up as per the instructions, i got it running on local with `gulp serve`. I could signin and add/delete/update todos as expected. However, a colleague of mine who did the same thing is getting the following error
[image]

My colleague is working from the Philippines if that matters at all. Could someone please advise how I can get it working on his local machine? We're both using Chrome btw and he does not run into any issues using a version that was deployed to firebase, just encountering the error on localhost. Thanks.

Comment: did you run 'gulp serve:dist' and then send him the dist directory?

Comment: He cloned the repo and did the npm and bower install stuff and then ran gulp and gulp serve. I.e he's running the app on local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the firebase element as explained [here](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list/issues/12). Updating the firebase element solved the problem.